# MySQL: Unable to drop/remove foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints, ddl

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
mysql> alter table wp_delayedCoupons_visits remove foreign key fk_targets_visits;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'foreign key fk_targets_visits' at line 1

mysql> alter table wp_delayedCoupons_visits drop foreign key fk_targets_visits;
ERROR 1091 (42000): Can't DROP 'fk_targets_visits'; check that column/key exists
```

And also with backticks

```
mysql> alter table `wp_delayedCoupons_visits` remove foreign key `fk_targets_visits`;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'foreign key `fk_targets_visits`' at line 1

mysql> alter table `wp_delayedCoupons_visits` drop foreign key `fk_targets_visits`;
ERROR 1091 (42000): Can't DROP 'fk_targets_visits'; check that column/key exists

mysql> show columns in wp_delayedCoupons_visits;

+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| visitId           | mediumint(5) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| visitorId         | mediumint(9) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| urlVisited        | varchar(500) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| fk_targets_visits | mediumint(5) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Does anyone have an idea what may causing the constraint not to drop or be removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You obviously have a `column` called `fk_targets_visits`, but not a foreign key constraint even named with a `fk_` prefix.

look up by using

```
show create table `wp_delayedCoupons_visits`
```

if a forign key exists in this table, and then reissue your command by

```
alter table `wp_delayedCoupons_visits` drop foreign key fk_coup_visits
```

assuming a foreign key name `fk_coup_visits` really exists.

Answer (score 2):

> `alter table wp_delayedCoupons_visits remove foreign key fk_targets_visits;`

The error message says it all. There is syntax error because, nothing like `remove` exist for dropping keys in mysql.

> `alter table wp_delayedCoupons_visits drop foreign key fk_targets_visits;`

The syntax is correct, but you are actually trying to drop the key using the `column name (fk_targets_visits)`, rather you have to use actual `constraint name` in stead of `fk_targets_visits`. If you don't know the constraint name used or it is assigned by default, use following query to find out the constraint name (Change `DB_NAME` with your actual database name):

```
SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE
REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DB_NAME' AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'wp_delayedCoupons_visits' AND REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME = 'fk_targets_visits';
```